# Casting Poco::SharedPtr into another with different release policy

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, poco-libraries

I'm using POCO C++ library.

I have a class A that's inherit from IA and from Destructable.
A and IA got the dtor protected (not my choice)

```cpp
    class Destructable {
    public:
     virtual void destroy() = 0;
    };

    class IA
    {
     protected:
       ~IA();
    }

    class A : public IA, public Destructable
    {
       void destroy() {

       protected:
       ~IA();
    }
```

I manage to get a sharedPtr on A. To manage this, I create a NullReleasePolicy that d'ont calls the dtor and a custom SharedPtr object

```cpp
template <class C>
class NullReleasePolicy
    /// The null release policy for SharedPtr, which don't delete pointer
{
public:
    static void release(C* pObj)
        /// DON'T delete the object.
    {
        //nothing to do
    }
};

template <class C>
class DestructableReleasePolicy
{
public:
    static void release(C* pObj)
    {
        if (dynamic_cast<Destructable*>(pObj) != NULL)
            pObj->destroy();
    }
};

template<class T>
using DestructableSharedPtr = Poco::SharedPtr<T, Poco::ReferenceCounter, DestructableReleasePolicy<T> >;

template<class T>
using NonDestructableSharedPtr = Poco::SharedPtr<T, Poco::ReferenceCounter, NullReleasePolicy<T> >;
```

I would like to get a shared pointer on IA.

I understand that's .cast() method of a sharedPtr returns a sharedPtr with the same Release Policy (RP). In my case it's not possible because I can't call destroy() on IA.

I see that's = operator can change the RP. So Itry using this code

```cpp
DestructableSharedPtr<A> a = createA();
        
NonDestructableSharedPtr<A> tmp = a;
NonDestructableSharedPtr<IA> ia = tmp.cast<IA>();
```

And I got the compilation error

```
.../poco/poco-1.10.1-all/include/Poco/SharedPtr.h: Dans l'instanciation de «void Poco::SharedPtr<C, RC, RP>::release() [with C = IA; RC = Poco::ReferenceCounter; RP = NullReleasePolicy<A>]» :
.../poco-1.10.1-all/include/Poco/SharedPtr.h:161:10:   requis par «Poco::SharedPtr<C, RC, RP>::~SharedPtr() [with C = IA; RC = Poco::ReferenceCounter; RP = NullReleasePolicy<A>]»
myFile.cpp:84:114:   requis depuis ici
.../poco/poco-1.10.1-all/include/Poco/SharedPtr.h:443:15: erreur: no matching function for call to «NullReleasePolicy<A>::release(IA*&)»
```

It's like the IA object is embedded in a sharedPtr<IA, CP, NullReleasePolicy> instead of sharedPtr<IA, CP, NullReleasePolicy>. If you take a look a the cast implementation it is logical.

I don't know if there is a manner to do the job for my case.

Sorry my post is a quite long but it was necessary to expose all information.

Comment: I think the cast is only needed when you need to dynamic cast to a more derived class.  So I think you can 
    `DestructableSharedPtr<IA> a = createA();
    NonDestructableSharedPtr<IA> tmp = a;`

Comment: It's what I have done. Thx.